# Magento: Adding a custom EAV attribute that autopopulates with its default value on entity creation

Tags: php, magento, default-value, entity-attribute-value, populate

Is there a way to add a custom EAV attribute that automatically gets set to its default value upon creation of a new entity?

I set `eav_attribute.is_required` to `1` and `eav_attribute.default_value` to `0` (the default value), but it's not setting the attribute automatically when I create a new object.

By the way, the EAV entity type is `shipment`. I'm working on an installation of 1.3.2.4, before sales data was stored in flat tables.

EDIT

**Jonathan Day asked "how are you adding the attribute?"**

In ModuleDir\sql\module_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php, I have the following code:

```
$eav = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('sales_setup');
$eav->addAttribute('shipment', 'fieldname', array('type' => 'int'));
```

I also have the this code for later versions of Magento (after the sales entities went from EAV to flat tables):

```
$w = $this->_conn;
$table = $this->getTable('sales_flat_shipment');
$w->addColumn($table, 'fieldname', 'int');
$w->addKey($table, 'fieldname', 'fieldname', 'index');
```

**Jonathan Day asked "Have you checked that the attribute is added to eav_attribute with the correct fields?"**

Yes, it has been added to eav_attribute. And the attribute is settable and gettable.

Comment: how are you adding the attribute?  In an sql setup file or extending `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`?.  Have you checked that the attribute is added to `eav_attribute` with the correct fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `Varien_Object::getData()` (in `/lib/Varien/Object.php`) you can see the following line:

```
$default = null;
```

...and any instance of missing data returns `$default`. So the default value you set in your attribute is being ignored.

Since any undefined 'get' is handled by `getData()` it means a `null` will always be the default. It seems the only option is to override `Sales_Model_Order_Shipment` (or whichever entity model it is) and provide custom getters.

A simple example would be:

```
function getSample()
{
    if (!$this->hasSample())
        return 0;

    return $this->getData('sample');
}
```